# Using \newline in longtable in Overleaf interrupts table continused

Tags: line-breaking, longtable, overleaf

I've created a longtable in Overleaf which has 10 rows in total (one for each author). I've used `\newline` to space out the RoB in the final column. However, this interrupts the 'table continued on next page by pushing it to the page above the table. I'd like to be able to separate out all the RoB results onto separate but can't seem to find a fix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag,color} % for postscript graphics files
  \graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{amsmath}               % assumes amsmath package installed
  \allowdisplaybreaks[1]           % allow eqnarrays to break across pages
\usepackage{amssymb}               % assumes amsmath package installed 
\usepackage{url}                   % format hyperlinks correctly
\usepackage{rotating}              % allow portrait figures and tables
\usepackage{multirow}              % allows merging of rows in tables
\usepackage{lscape}                % allows pages to be typeset in landscape mode
\usepackage{tabularx}              % allows fixed width tables
\usepackage{verbatim}              % enhanced version of built-in verbatim environment
\usepackage{footnote}              % allows more control over footnote environments
\usepackage{float}                 % allows H option on floats to force here placement
\usepackage{booktabs}              % improve table line spacing
\usepackage{subcaption}            % for multiple sub-figures in a single float
\usepackage{siunitx}               % add SI units

% Add your packages here
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{vcell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \small
    
    \begin{longtable}{ 
     p{0.1\dimexpr \textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}|
     p{0.2\dimexpr \textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}|
     p{0.1\dimexpr \textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}|
     p{0.4\dimexpr \textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}|
     p{0.1\dimexpr \textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}|
     p{0.4\dimexpr \textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}|
    }
    \caption{Characteristics of included reviews} \label{tab:long} \\
    
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Author / year}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Synthesis type}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Search dates}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{PICO}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{No of RCTs}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{RoB (\%)}} \\ 
    \hline 
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{6}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Author / year}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Synthesis type}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Search dates}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{PICO}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{No of RCTs}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{RoB (\%)}} \\ \hline 
    \endhead
    
    \hline \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot
    
    \hline \hline
    \endlastfoot
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Insert first author %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    Staley et al., 2021 & Meta-analysis & 1946 to 2020 & {\textbf{Population:} Women eligible to participate in a cervical cancer screening program as defined by the entry criteria for that program, including women due, overdue, those returning for repeat screening and women returning for follow up after abnormal result} 
    
    \newline{\textbf{Intervention:} Invitations, reminders, education, message framing, counselling, risk factor assessment, procedures, and economic interventions} \newline{\textbf{Comparison:} No intervention or routine / standard care} \newline{\textbf{Outcomes:} Uptake of cervical screening} 
    
    & 70 
    
    & {\textbf{Cochrane risk of bias tool:}} \newline 
    
    {\textbf{Random sequence generation}} \newline Low risk (33 studies; 47\%) \newline Unclear (35 studies; 50\%) \newline High risk (2 studies; 3\%) 
    
    {\textbf{Allocation concealment}} \newline Low risk (11 studies; 16\%) \newline Unclear (57 studies; 81\%) \newline High risk (2 studies; 3\%)
    
    {\textbf{Blinding: all outcomes}} \newline Low risk (9 studies; 13\%) \newline Unclear (59 studies; 84\%) \newline High risk (2 studies; 3\%)
    
    {\textbf{Incomplete outcome data, all outcomes}} \newline Low risk (42 studies; 60\%) \newline Unclear (9 studies; 13\%) \newline High risk (18 studies; 26\%) 
    
    {\textbf{Incomplete outcome data, all outcomes}} \newline Low risk (42 studies; 60\%) \newline Unclear (9 studies; 13\%) \newline High risk (18 studies; 26\%) 
    
    {\textbf{Incomplete outcome data, all outcomes}} \newline Low risk (42 studies; 60\%) \newline Unclear (9 studies; 13\%) \newline High risk (18 studies; 26\%) 
    
    \\
    
    \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a compilable reproducible example including a class and the necessary packages?

Comment: unrelated but never use `\begin{center}` around `longtable`

Comment: Okay removed the centre and added the class and packages (sorry I know there's more here than is needed for this table but it was easier to copy the whole thing). Does this help? Thanks Diane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

- Your problem is independent from Overlief (which is just editor)
- For your table instead of `longtable` rather use `\longtblr` of `tabularray`. Some benefits: much shorter table code, clear structure, simple to define ratios between column width.
- Instead of `\newline` is better to use lists (in two level) as defined in `enumitem` package. By this the problem at use of `\newline` in the cells text is removed.
- You should be aware, that all kinds of long tables can be broken between pages only between rows. Since your table is (due to repeated rows) a bit to tall that repetition of the second row can be fit in one page, it is pushed to the next page in landscape environment. This problem can be handled on two ways:

  - reduce font size to `\footnotesize` or
  - increase text area on page (by use of the `geometry` package)
- To show how how `longtblr` works, in MWE below is used second option and second row repeated three times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=20mm]{geometry} % added

\usepackage{pdflscape}        
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{xcolor}                 % changed
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, varwidth}  % added
\usepackage{enumitem}               % added

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  label={},  % <---
                  leftmargin=*,
                  itemsep=1ex,
                }
\setlist[itemize,2]{itemsep=0ex}
%
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
    \SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
                    }
    \small
\begin{longtblr}[
  theme = fancy,
caption = {Characteristics of included reviews},
  label = {tab:long} 
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {*{3}{X[h, l]} 
                                  X[3.0, l, h] 
                                  X[0.6, c, h]  
                                  X[3.0, l, h] },
                  colsep = 4pt,
                  row{1}  = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries, c, m},
                  measure = vbox,            % <===
                  stretch = -1, %<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                                % with "nosep" option; tabularray doc p.51
%
                  rowhead = 1,
                  }
% column headers
Author/ year
    &   Synthesis type 
        &   Search dates 
            &   PICO 
                &   No of RCTs 
                    &  RoB (\%)           
                    \\ 
% table body
Staley et al., 2021
    & Meta-analysis
        & 1946 to 2020
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Cochrane risk of bias tool:}
                    \item   \textbf{Random sequence generation}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (33 studies; \qty{47}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (35 studies; \qty{50}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Allocation concealment}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item    Low risk (11 studies; \qty{16}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (57 studies; \qty{81}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Blinding: all outcomes}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item    Low risk (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item    Unclear (59 studies; \qty{84}{\%})
                        \item    High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Incomplete outcome data, all outcomes}
                           \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (42 studies; \qty{60}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (18 studies; \qty{26}{\%})    \\
                            \end{itemize}
                        \end{itemize}
                        & 70 &  \begin{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Cochrane risk of bias tool:}
                    \item   \textbf{Random sequence generation}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (33 studies; \qty{47}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (35 studies; \qty{50}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                                       \item   \textbf{Allocation concealment}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (11 studies; \qty{16}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (57 studies; \qty{81}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Blinding: all outcomes}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item    Low risk (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item    Unclear (59 studies; \qty{84}{\%})
                        \item    High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Incomplete outcome data, all outcomes}
                           \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (42 studies; \qty{60}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (18 studies; \qty{26}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                        \end{itemize}                           \\
%%
Staley et al., 2021
    & Meta-analysis
        & 1946 to 2020
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Cochrane risk of bias tool:}
                    \item   \textbf{Random sequence generation}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (33 studies; \qty{47}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (35 studies; \qty{50}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Allocation concealment}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item    Low risk (11 studies; \qty{16}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (57 studies; \qty{81}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Blinding: all outcomes}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item    Low risk (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item    Unclear (59 studies; \qty{84}{\%})
                        \item    High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Incomplete outcome data, all outcomes}
                           \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (42 studies; \qty{60}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (18 studies; \qty{26}{\%})    \\
                            \end{itemize}
                        \end{itemize}
                        & 70 &  \begin{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Cochrane risk of bias tool:}
                    \item   \textbf{Random sequence generation}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (33 studies; \qty{47}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (35 studies; \qty{50}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                                       \item   \textbf{Allocation concealment}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (11 studies; \qty{16}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (57 studies; \qty{81}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Blinding: all outcomes}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item    Low risk (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item    Unclear (59 studies; \qty{84}{\%})
                        \item    High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Incomplete outcome data, all outcomes}
                           \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (42 studies; \qty{60}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (18 studies; \qty{26}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                        \end{itemize}                           \\
%%
Staley et al., 2021
    & Meta-analysis
        & 1946 to 2020
                    &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Cochrane risk of bias tool:}
                    \item   \textbf{Random sequence generation}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (33 studies; \qty{47}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (35 studies; \qty{50}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Allocation concealment}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item    Low risk (11 studies; \qty{16}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (57 studies; \qty{81}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Blinding: all outcomes}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item    Low risk (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item    Unclear (59 studies; \qty{84}{\%})
                        \item    High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Incomplete outcome data, all outcomes}
                           \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (42 studies; \qty{60}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (18 studies; \qty{26}{\%})    \\
                            \end{itemize}
                        \end{itemize}
                        & 70 &  \begin{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Cochrane risk of bias tool:}
                    \item   \textbf{Random sequence generation}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (33 studies; \qty{47}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (35 studies; \qty{50}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                                       \item   \textbf{Allocation concealment}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (11 studies; \qty{16}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (57 studies; \qty{81}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Blinding: all outcomes}
                            \begin{itemize}
                        \item    Low risk (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item    Unclear (59 studies; \qty{84}{\%})
                        \item    High risk (2 studies; \qty{3}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                    \item   \textbf{Incomplete outcome data, all outcomes}
                           \begin{itemize}
                        \item   Low risk (42 studies; \qty{60}{\%})
                        \item   Unclear (9 studies; \qty{13}{\%})
                        \item   High risk (18 studies; \qty{26}{\%})
                            \end{itemize}
                        \end{itemize}                           \\
    \end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated. :)

Comment: @LadyoftheWater ,You are welcome!